# Best continuous-categorical approach for this case

Tags: anova

Thanks for the answers, I am explaining again what I am trying to achieve.

Let's assume I surveyed 3000 people, 2 questions (eye color and monthly income), resulting in a dataset that has one categorical variable with three different values corresponding to eye colors (brown, blue, green, all them repeated in 3000 responses) and a continuous variable with 3000 numerical values from 1110 to 12030 (corresponding to the "income" question).

From that dataset, I want to understand the best approach to say something like: "when color is Brown, people earn between 8030 and 9099; when color is blue, income is between 3001 and 4039;...).

In summary I would like to:

1- from each categorical value (e.g. "brown"), create a continuos interval ("8030 to 9099"); the interval is not random should be something created with statistical meaning based on relationship strength / r coefficient / p-value

2- sort those relationships by their statistical significance, and clarify if there is a relationship with not sufficient statistical meaning (example, if the continuous values for "Green" were heavily dispersed, and I could not create an interval that make sense)

Comment: How would you get the mean and sd?

Comment: e.g. I asked for "favorite color" and "income"; 5 respondents answered "Red", and each of them also answered  "198, 199, 200, 201, 202" (so average "income" when color is RED = 200; std dev = 1.41).

Comment: But that's not what your question says. It says you only got income in intervals